# Using kAIron as a ChatOps for Jenkins 2.0

Tags: jenkins

I am attempting to use an Open Source product called [kAIron](https://github.com/digiteinfotech/kairon) for implementing NLP based ChatOps system for our DevOps pipelines built using Jenkins 2.0.
So two questions.

1. Is it even possible to achieve, or is this not something for which this product is built?
2. If yes, can someone point me to the documentation or get started kind of tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am one of the core contributors of kAIron, I will able to answer your questions.

1. Yes, it is possible to achieve, as kAIron helps users to train the bot.
2. you can try [kAIron](https://kairon.digite.com), or you can do [manual deployment](https://www.digite.com/kairon/getting-started/)

As Kairon is under active development so we are happy to answer any questions you may have on our [Github](https://github.com/digiteinfotech/kairon) page
We are fairly active in our responses

Comment: Thanks, @Fahad, It's a good start but a lot needs to be documented. I would love to contribute if time permits.

Answer (score 1):

Here are getting started videos for Kairon . We have started documentation . So please have patience with us .

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCT5GAEluyaugvORqPwf-WRw/playlists

Thanks